# Jupyter Notebook looks weird on github

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I am pushing code from an AWS SageMaker instance to my GitHub. The Jupyter Notebooks are looking very weird on GitHub after I pushed. Example below:

[image]

There are these huge spaces at the top and bottom. For **each cell** it  insert **one empty line at the top** of each cell and **four empty lines at the bottom**. This is obviously not the case when I wrote the code in the notebook. Only after I pushed to GitHub. It's make the notebooks look very bad on GitHub.

Has anyone an idea why that is the case and/or has seen this before?

Comment: I had seen this on gists recently. I wonder where this issue is being tracked? I believe they'll fix it. For now, [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/) renders them fine. Already there was several issues with GitHub's rendering so that I try to impress upon people that the GitHub browser view is only a preview mode for developers. The URL for the nbviewer view of GitHub pages is easy to figure out, just change the `https://github.com/` part  at the start of the GitHub URL notebook page to `https://nbviewer.org/github...`. That saves you filling in the form to get the link.

Comment: [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/) is provided by the Jupyter community for viewing and sharing 'static' versions of notebooks online with stakeholders & non-developers. It supports a lot of things the GitHub preview doesn't even with [the latest update](https://twitter.com/HamelHusain/status/1590473444206215168). I put 'static' in quotes because it actually does maintain interactive things backed by javascript, which GitHub's preview fails to do. Meaning that things such as Plotly plots, D3-backed code, & animations with frames generated previously, **all  remain interactive and working.

Comment: Oops, I had overlooked the whitespace in Hamel Husain's heralding of the updates even. See top and bottom of second code cell in [post here](https://twitter.com/HamelHusain/status/1590473444206215168). (I tried tweeting someone who may be able to provide insight or pass it along.) For comparison: Nbviewer rendered-view [of that post can be seen in your browser here](https://nbviewer.org/github/fastai/fastdiffusion/blob/master/nbs/johno/FastAI_Minimal_Decrappifying_Diffusion_%28flowers%29.ipynb).

Comment: Any update on this issue? My .ipynb file has the same issue it has unnecessary space in each cell

Comment: Use nbviewer as suggested above, @VengenzzVicky. That has always worked and continues to render nicely and have more features than the Github preview render. You can just change the front of the URL to go to the page.

Comment: Noting here to keep related posts somehow linked that there's similar topic brought up about gists at [Random newlines in Github Gist iPython notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74781862/8508004).

Comment: nbviewer works for public repositories. Unfortunately not for private ones. Which would be the case for me. Is there maybe any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I found out about this github issue about Ipython.

**The browser version would causes to create empty spaces.** https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5612

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying! I updated my chrome version. Unfortunately the issue still persists.

Comment: That issue is from 2014 @Mert and I think it refers to when you are actively running the notebook. The OP is about rendering of static notebooks at GitHub, I think.