# Random newlines in Github Gist iPython notebooks

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, gist

I have noticed across all of my Jupyter notebooks stored as Github Gists that newlines have been added to them, in both new and old notebooks. Am I doing something wrong? Here is an example:

[image]

The code for the first block is:

```json
{
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 26,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "data": {
      "text/plain": [
       "torch.Size([30522])"
      ]
     },
     "execution_count": 26,
     "metadata": {},
     "output_type": "execute_result"
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "import torch\n",
    "\n",
    "vec = torch.max(\n",
    "    torch.log(\n",
    "        1 + torch.relu(output.logits)\n",
    "    ) * tokens.attention_mask.unsqueeze(-1),\n",
    "dim=1)[0].squeeze()\n",
    "\n",
    "vec.shape"
   ]
  }
```

And the [link](https://gist.github.com/jamescalam/7778af63b109f5e69580732662632e1c)

Comment: Nothing was added. It's just rendering clunkily for now. I don't know if GitHub intends to fix this. A lot of newer users aren't aware that the GitHub rendering is best thought of as a preview and you should be using [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/). A few years ago GitHub only rendered very small notebooks and new users would learn more quickly about nbviewer. Go to that link and put in the URL and you'll get your notebook nicely rendered [here](https://nbviewer.org/gist/jamescalam/7778af63b109f5e69580732662632e1c). The URLS follow a simple pattern if you study them and so you can skip ...

Comment: the form once you learn the pattern. See more about this in my comments to this post [here with the title 'Jupyter Notebook looks weird on github'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74730156/8508004). Nbviewer's 'static' view actually actively renders a lot of things where javascript is the underlying engine, like Plotly plots and D3 plots. GitHub doesn't do that and suffers several other shortcomings. The nbviewer render is better to share with non-developers, too.